# Grunt - npm module not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt and I'm having trouble setting up a project with new plugins.

So far I have:

1. installed grunt-cli globally
2. installed grunt-init globally
3. downloaded the gruntfile template from the GIT repository
4. created a new directory 'test' and navigated to the directory in Terminal
5. created a new grunt project from the template (grunt-init gruntfile)
6. installed the project dependencies (npm install)

This all works great, however I want to use a different uglify plugin so, still in the 'test' directory, I run:

```
npm install uglify-js --save-dev
```

As I'm not using the global flag, the plugin downloads to test/node_modules directory as expected, existing at test/node_modules/uglify-js. The package.json file has been updated with the additional dependency:

```
"uglify-js": "^2.4.15"
```

I then edit Gruntfile.js, adding

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('uglify-js');
```

And change

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);
```

To

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify-js']);
```

I run

```
npm install
```

to ensure all dependencies are downloaded, but now when I run the grunt task I get this error:

```
Local Npm module "uglify-js" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "uglify-js" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Mac OS X 10.8.5, Node v0.10.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use UglifyJS whit grunt, you should use [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify). Install it with:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

enable it inside your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

and run your task:

```
grunt uglify
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#getting-started) for more information.

Comment: I should have specified that the grunt-contrib-uglify plugin is included with the gruntfile template. I was under the impression that an option I was passing in (compress: {drop_console: true}) was not working, when in fact it was… My original question is more theoretical now - was grunt complaining because the uglify-js module is a generic Node module, not a Grunt plugin?

Comment: Yes @Terry. When you want to automate the use of a npm module with grunt.js, it's desirable that you use (or write your own if it doesn't exists) a plugin. Maybe you could use an npm module without a plugin, but you would have to do a lot of unnecessary configuration, which is already done by the plugin. I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on windows 7. I resolved this issue by creating a package.json with the below modules.

```
"grunt": "~0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
"grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0"
```

Ran npm install and it started working within that directory.